# Is it valid to reuse the same React-Redux's useDispatch on multiple components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have multiple modals and the conditions for showing and hiding them are stored in a Redux store. To avoid typos I export the actions like this...

```
//reduxStuff.js

export const modalNameHide = () => {
  return { type: "MODALNAMEHIDE" };
};

export const modalNameShow = () => {
  return { type: "MODALNAMESHOW" };
};
```

Then when I need the functionality for hiding a modal I do this...

```
//HideModalButton.js

import { modalNameHide } from "reduxStuff";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const HideModalNameButton = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return <button onClick = {() => { dispatch(modalNameHide()) }>Close Modal<button>
}
```

As you can see for every component that needs to update the store, 2 imports must be done, one for *useDispatch* and one for the needed action (*modalNameHide* in this example).

So my question boils down to this: Can I import *useDispatch* in *reduxStuff.js* and export *useDispatch* and *modalNameHide* together?

Something like this...

```
//reduxStuff.js

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const modalNameHide = () => {
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch({ type: "MODALNAMEHIDE" });
};

export const modalNameShow = () => {
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch({ type: "MODALNAMESHOW" });
};
```

Now when I need to close a modal I would just do one import like this...

```
//HideModalButton.js

import { modalNameHide } from "reduxStuff";

const HideModalNameButton = () => {
    return <button onClick = {() => { modalNameHide() }>Close Modal<button>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not valid.

In your first case, you're doing `useDispatch()` during **render**, and then you call `dispatch(modalNameHide())` during **onClick**. This is valid and correct usage of `useDispatch`.

In your theoretical second case, you're doing `modalNameHide()` during **onClick**, and this means that `useDispatch()` will also be used during **onClick** instead of render (which is incorrect usage of `useDispatch`).

`useDispatch` is a react hook, and you're breaking the Rules of Hooks. Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. Btw do you have any idea how to avoid the "two imports" problem?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

As *grumd* said, I was breaking the rules of hooks by doing what I did. However I just figured out what the solution is. All I had to do was make a custom hook.

```
//reduxStuff.js

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const useModalNameHide = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return () => {
    dispatch({ type: "MODALNAMEHIDE" });
  };
};

export const useModalNameShow = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return () => {
    dispatch({ type: "MODALNAMEHIDE" });
  };
};
```

.

```
//HideModalButton.js

import { useModalNameHide } from "reduxStuff";

const HideModalNameButton = () => {
    const modalNameHide = useModalNameHide()
    return <button onClick = {() => { modalNameHide() }>Close Modal<button>
}
```